# How to find complete log likelihood for mixture of PPCA

Tags: probability, pca, likelihood

In Appendix C of a [paper by Michael E. Tipping and Christopher M. Bishop](http://www.miketipping.com/papers/met-mppca.pdf) about mixture models for probabilistic PCA, the probability of a single data vector $\mathbf{t}$ is expressed as a mixture of PCA models (equation 69):

$$
p(\mathbf{t}) = \sum_{i=1}^M\pi_i p(\mathbf{t}|i)
$$

where $\pi$ is the mixing proportion and $p(\mathbf{t}|i)$ is a single probabilistic PCA model.

The model underlying the probabilistic PCA method is (equation 2)

$$
\mathbf{t} = \mathbf{Wx} + \boldsymbol\mu + \boldsymbol\epsilon.
$$
Where $\mathbf{x}$ is a latent variable. By introducing a new set of variables $z_{ni}$ "labelling which model is responsible for generating each data point $\mathbf{t}_n$", Bishop formulates the complete log likelihood as (equation 70):

$$
\mathcal{L}_C = \sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^Mz_{ni}\ln\{\pi_ip(\mathbf{t}_n, \mathbf{x}_{ni})\}.
$$
I would like to understand how he derives this expression as he doesn't provide a solution himself. **How is this expression for the complete log likelihood found?**

Answer (score 1):

So far the observed likelihood is:
$$
L(\pi) = \prod_{n=1}^Np(\mathbf{t_n}) = \prod_{n=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^M \pi_ip(\mathbf{t}_n|i)\right)
$$
and the observed log likelihood is given by:
$$
l(\pi) =\sum_{n=1}^N \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^M \pi_ip(\mathbf{t}_n|i)\right)
$$

If we consider the complete data, we invoke the use of auxiliary variable $Z$ which is unobserved, but it indicates which group the data $\mathbf{t_n}$ belongs to. Think of $Z_n$ as a one hot vector with with the $i^{th}$ entry being $1$ indicating the $i^{th}$ group amoung all $M$ groups which the data $\mathbf{t_n}$ belongs in.

Now $Z$ will be a $N\times M$ matrix with only one entry per row being $1$ and the rest $0$

We know that $\pi_i = \sum_{n=1}^NZ_{ni}/N$.

To write the complete log-likelihood, we need the joint density of $\mathbf{t}_n$ and $z_{n}$
$$
p(\mathbf{t}_n, \mathbf{z}_{n}) = p(\mathbf{t}_n|\mathbf{z}_{n})p(\mathbf{z}_n)
$$
Suppose that Z_{ni} = 1 then
$$
p(\mathbf{t}_n|z_{ni}) = p(\mathbf{t}_n)\\
p(z_{ni} = 1) = P(z_{ni} = 1) = \pi_i\\
\implies p(\mathbf{t}_n, z_{ni} = 1) = \pi_ip(\mathbf{t}_n)
$$

Thus for a given complete data, the contribution to the likelihood is $\left(\pi_ip(\mathbf{t}_n)\right)^{z_ni}$

Hence
$$
L_c = \prod_{n=1}^N\prod_{i=1}^M \left[\pi_ip(\mathbf{t}_n)\right]^{z_{ni}}
=\prod_{n=1}^N\prod_{i=1}^M \Big[\pi_ip(\mathbf{t}_n|i)\Big]^{z_{ni}}\\
$$

Therefore
$$
l_c = \sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^M z_{ni}\log\Big(\pi_ip(\mathbf{t}_n|i)\Big)\\
$$